# Why does xUnit test throw AggregateException?

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

This is the setup of my tests classes:

```
[CollectionDefinition("MyCollection")]
public class MyDefinition : ICollectionFixture<DBName> { }

[Collection("MyCollection")]
public class MyTestBase
{
    protected readonly ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper;
    protected DBName db;

    public MyTestBase(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper, DBName db)
    {
        this.testOutputHelper = testOutputHelper;
        this.db = db;
    }
}

[Collection("MyCollection")]
public class MyTests : MyTestBase
{
    public MyTests (ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper, DBName db) : base(testOutputHelper, db)
    {
        testOutputHelper.WriteLine(db);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void testA() { //Asserts }

    [Fact]
    public void testB() { //Asserts }
}
```

When I run MyTests one test runs without an error, but the other generates exception:

```
System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Cannot find table 0.) (The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: DBName db)
---- System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Cannot find table 0.
---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: DBName db
```

What is the flaw in this setup and why does it generate error.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, and I am confused, because fixture works for one test but not for the other.

Comment: are you sure the `IndexOutOfRangeException` isn't coming from your fixture? and it is trying to tell you about both problems?

Comment: also: what is `optDB` / `OptimaDB`? those things aren't shown in the code

Comment: It just prints the db name to be sure it is the same for the whole collection of classes. Renamed it to db ...

Comment: I doubt that it is from the fixture. If it works for one test the same fixture should be injected for the other.

Comment: The code you shared does not have any part which can throw such exception...you might want to debug the test and figure out which code throws the exception and share that details here.